# Overflow-x Issues with Side tab Widget

Tags: jquery, css, html

Does anybody know how to fix the horizontal scrolling on this demo?
http://codepen.io/SimonNonnis/debug/GaufE

The purpose is to open the widget only on click, but just spotted that there is an horizontal scroll

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

Solved creating a site wrapper div inside the body and applying the overflow-x:hidden to the wrapper INSTEAD of the body or html.

http://codepen.io/SimonNonnis/debug/GaufE